# c# - Trying to populate textbox and listview from txt file

Tags: c#, winforms, file, streamreader

I'm only able to load the textbox and can't seem to get the listview to populate. But, after I remove `this.textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();` listview has populated. Here's code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    string line = String.Empty;
    this.textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd(); // remove it, listview working
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(new char[0]);
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem
        {
            Text = data[0]
        };
        item.SubItems.Add(data[1]);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Screenshots:
[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8NIo.png)
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5faJ7.png)

Comment: ReadToEnd will read entire file at once which is causing the while loop to null

Comment: @User965207: Does ReadToEnd can't work with ReadLine?

Comment: Why new `char[0]` ? Can you add an example of the file content to the question to have the file format, please?

Comment: ReadToEnd will read the file till the end . Readline will be null as the file is already read .  the while condition will fail @phamtien

Comment: I using char[0] to split multiple space or tab.

Comment: Issue has solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following.

ReadToEnd does this: Reads all characters from the current position to the end of the stream. You are losing the position of the stream.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    string line = String.Empty;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // this.textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd(); // remove it, listview working
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(new char[0]);
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem
        {
            Text = data[0]
        };
        item.SubItems.Add(data[1]);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
    this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `sr.ReadToEnd()` reads the file upto its end, and that's why `ReadLine()` is of no use.

Let's read the file *line by line* and update `text` (which we'll assign to `this.textBox1.Text`) and `listView1.Items`:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

bool firstLine = true; 

// We don't want redrawing after each ListViewItem adding
listView1.BeginUpdate();

try {
  // File.ReadLines is easier to manipulate with StreamReader
  // if you want just read lines
  foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
    if (!firstLine)
      sb.AppendLine();

    sb.Append(line);
    firstLine = false; 

    // 3: We want at most 3 chunks (item, subitem and tail to throw away)
    string[] data = line.Split(new char[0], 3);

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem() {
      Text = data[0]
    };

    if (data.Length > 1)
      item.SubItems.Add(data[1]);

    listView1.Items.Add(item);
  }
}
finally {
  // The file has been scanned, items added; now we a ready to redraw the listView1   
  listView1.EndUpdate();
}

this.textBox1.Text = text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
foreach ( string line in lines )
{
  var items = line.Split(new char[0]);
  if ( items.Length > 0 )
  {
    var item = new ListViewItem(items[0]);
    if ( items.Length > 1 )
      item.SubItems.Add(items[1]);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
  }
}
```